# Radio button and normal button are not communicating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
        <title>BookStore</title>
        <style>
            img{
             width: 250px;
                 height: 300px;
         float: none;
            }
        button {
         fl
        </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function fn1(){
        var rd1 = document.getElementById("rd1");
        var rd2 = document.getElementById("rd2");

        if(rd1.checked==true)
            alert("the channel selected is: " + rd1.value);
        else if(rd2.checked==true)
            alert("the channel selected is: " + rd2.value);
        else
            alert("nothing is selected.");
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>Welcome to my Bookstore</h1></center>
    <br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="book1" class="col">
            <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="book2" class="col">
            <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="book3" class="col">
            <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction()" id="btn1.1" class="hide">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction1()" id="btn1.2" class="show">Show</button>
<input id="rd1" name="grp1" type="radio" value="simple snippets"> simple </input>
            &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp; 

            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction2()" id="btn2.1" class="hide1">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction3()" id="btn2.2" class="show1">Show</button>

            &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp; 

            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction4()" id="btn3.1" class="hide2">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction5()" id="btn3.2" class="show2">Show</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<input id="rd2" name="grp1" type="radio" value="Telusko Learnings">Telusko Learnings</input>

        <div class="row">
            <div  id="book4" class="col">
                    <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="book5" class="col">
                    <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="book6" class="col">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction6()" id="btn4.1" class="hide3">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction7()" id="btn4.2" class="show3">Show</button>

            &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp;

            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction8()" id="btn5.1" class="hide4">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction9()" id="btn5.2" class="show4">Show</button>

            &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp;

            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction10()" id="btn6.1" class="hide5">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction11()" id="btn6.2" class="show5">Show</button>

        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="book7" class="col">
                    <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="book8" class="col">
                    <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="book9" class="col">
                    <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction12()" id="btn7.1" class="hide6">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction13()" id="btn7.2" class="show6">Show</button>

            &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp;

            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction14()" id="btn8.1" class="hide7">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction15()" id="btn8.2" class="show7">Show</button>
        
            &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp;

            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction16()" id="btn9.1" class="hide8">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction17()" id="btn9.2" class="show8">Show</button>
        
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="book10" class="col">
                    <p></p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px;" onclick="myFunction18()" id="btn10.1" class="hide9">Hide</button>
            <button style="width:75px; hieght: 75px; visibility:hidden;" onclick="myFunction19()" id="btn10.2" class="show9">Show</button>
        
        </div>
    </div>

<button onlick="fn1()"> click me </button>
            
</div>
    <script src="sell-books.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code, when I run it the radio button shows up and the normal button will show up at the end. but then when I try to use the radio button and button together by selecting the radio button and then clicking the normal button nothing pops up. It is suppose to pop up saying which one was selected. i put the script I am using in the head just so you can see that too.

Comment: There is no code I can see.

Comment: sorry just updated it. it was giving me a problem posting and was trying  to figure it out

Comment: just saw i had a typo in the onclick button, it says onlick. lol

Comment: Aside, `<center>` is deprecated, use CSS instead (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a spelling mistake in you code. Here is a cleaned up example.

```js
function fn1() {
  var rd1 = document.getElementById("rd1");
  var rd2 = document.getElementById("rd2");

  if (rd1.checked == true)
    alert("the channel selected is: " + rd1.value);
  else if (rd2.checked == true)
    alert("the channel selected is: " + rd2.value);
  else
    alert("nothing is selected.");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>BookStore</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>Welcome to my Bookstore</h1>
  </center>
  <label><input id="rd1" name="grp1" type="radio" value="simple snippets" />simple snippets</label>
  <label><input id="rd2" name="grp1" type="radio" value="Telusko Learnings" />Telusko Learnings</label>
  <button onclick="fn1()"> click me </button>
</body>
</html>
```